# Que es la indireccion en herencia multiple en Python?

Tags: python, herencia

-Estaba leyendo un articulo `(https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)` sobre la funcion `super()` para herencia multiple en Python. Me llamo la atencion ya que, literalmente en la primera linea dice que si no estas asombrado con el funcionamiento de esta, quiere decir que no la conoces bien. El punto esta en que menciona que la principal ventaja de usar este  clase que referencia al padre mas cercano  esta en que, a diferencia de referenciar a la clase padre directamente, esta hace una busqueda no direccionada, lo cual se supone que es mejor. Primero he de decir que no domino al 100% el ingles lo cual es en parte el culpable de esta pregunta. Por otro lado, la pregunta finalmente seria: por que es mejor referenciar a una clase padre a traves de `super()`, es decir ...

```
class persona:
    def __init__(self, nombre, apellido, edad, sexo):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.apellido = apellido
        self.sexo = sexo
        self.edad = edad

class empleado(persona):
    def __init__(self, nombre, apellido, edad, sexo, salario):
        super().__init__(nombre, apellido,edad, sexo)
        self.salario = salario
```

-En lugar de referenciar a la clase padre a traves de la propia referencia ...

```
class persona:
    def __init__(self, nombre, apellido, edad, sexo):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.apellido = apellido
        self.sexo = sexo
        self.edad = edad

class empleado(persona):
    def __init__(self, nombre, apellido, edad, sexo, salario):
        persona.__init__(self,nombre, apellido,edad, sexo)
        self.salario = salario
```

Comment: si mas no me equivoco `super()` se usa para inicializar todas las clases padres, lo cual ayuda mucho en herencia múltiple, por ejemplo al tener 5 clases padres. Esto seria mas complicado de hacer con la forma *tradicional*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usar `super()` tiene dos ventajas:

1. Evitas poner explícitamente el nombre de la clase padre. Esto te da más flexibilidad al hacer el código de esas funciones independiente de la clase de la que heredan.

   Es decir, siguiendo tu ejemplo, si decides cambiar de idea y hacer que `Empleado`, en lugar de heredar de `Persona` herede de otra clase, digamos `Trabajador`, el código que pones como segundo ejemplo dejaría de funcionar correctamente, pues aún estaría llamando al constructor de `Persona` en lugar del de `Trabajador`. Para que funcionara correctamente tendrías que cambiar `Persona` por trabajador en *todos* los métodos de la clase `Empleado` (no tiene por qué aparecer sólo en `__init__()`, es frecuente que otros métodos también sean extendedidos en las clases derivadas).

   Usando `super()` no necesitas tocar nada de la clase `Empleado`, salvo la declaración de la propia `class` para indicar que ahora hereda de `Trabajador`.
2. La resolución de `super()` a la clase que hay que utilizar ocurre *en tiempo de ejecución* y no en tiempo de compilación. Esto permite mecanismos flexibles sobre todo ante herencia múltiple.

Para aclarar el punto 2, que es el más complejo, imagina que tenemos implementadas tus clases de ejemplo:

```
class Persona:
  def __init__(self, nombre, apellido, edad, sexo):
    print("Inicializando Persona")
    self.nombre = nombre
    self.apellido = apellido
    self.sexo = sexo
    self.edad = edad

class Empleado(Persona):
  def __init__(self, nombre, apellido, edad, sexo, salario):
    print("Inicializando Empleado")
    super().__init__(nombre, apellido, edad, sexo)
    self.salario = salario
```

Pero ahora queremos crear un nuevo tipo de "Persona" que sea una inteligencia artificial, la cual, además de no tener edad ni sexo (por lo que ignorará lo que reciba en esos dos parámetros), tendrá un atributo `is_a_bot`.

```
class InteligenciaArtificial(Persona):
  def __init__(self, nombre, apellido, edad, sexo):
    print("Inicializando IA")
    super().__init__(nombre, apellido, edad=None, sexo=None)
    self.is_a_bot = True
```

Pues bien, ahora viene la gracia del uso de `super()`. Podemos crear una nueva clase que sea un `EmpleadoAI` que herede a la vez de `Empleado` y de `InteligenciaArtificial`, escribiendo simplemente:

```
class EmpleadoAI(Empleado, InteligenciaArtificial):
  pass
```

El cuerpo de la clase está vacío (`pass`), por lo que su método `__init__()` en realidad no lo hemos escrito, sino que es heredado de `Empleado`. Pero cuando `Empleado` internamente hace `super().__init__()`, ahora su "super" ya no será `Persona`, sino `InteligenciaArtificial`, porque hemos metido esta clase "en medio" entre `Empleado` e `InteligenciaArtificial`.

La estructura de herencia es de tipo "diamante":

[image: Diagrama de herencia]

Pero Python tiene ese grafo "serializado" en lo que se denomina el MRO (*Method Resolution Order*) que depende del orden de declaración de las clases en el caso de herencia múltiple. Debido a que `EmpleadoAI` declara heredar primero de `Empleado` y después de `InteligenciaArtificial`, el MRO tendrá en ese orden estas dos clases (y después de ambas tendrá a `Persona`).

El MRO de una clase lo puedes consultar:

```
>>> EmpleadoAI.__mro__
(__main__.EmpleadoAI,
 __main__.Empleado,
 __main__.InteligenciaArtificial,
 __main__.Persona,
 object)
```

Es decir, cuando se intenta invocar un método de `EmpleadoAI`, se buscará primero en `EmpleadoAI`, y si no está ahí, en `Empleado` y después en `InteligenciaArtificial`, y finalmente en `Persona` (y si no en la clase `object` de la que todas heredan si no declaran otra).

Al ser `super()` evaluado en tiempo de ejecución, eso permite que se pueda saber si `Empleado.__init__()` fue invocado al instanciar un objeto `Empleado` (en cuyo caso `super()` resolvería hacia `Persona`), o si se está invocando vía otro `super()` desde `EmpleadoAI` (en cuyo caso resolvería hacia `InteligenciaArtificial`).

Un ejemplo de creación de objeto y de la salida que produce aclarará el comportamiento:

```
>>> e = EmpleadoAI("Cortana", "Microsoft", edad=100, sexo="Femenino", salario=2000)
Inicializando Empleado
Inicializando AI
Inicializando Persona
```

Vemos el orden en que se van llamando los constructores y cómo el de `InteligenciaArtificial` se ha "colado" entre `Empleado` y `Persona`. Podemos ver también que los atributos finalmente inicializados en este empleado especial son los de una IA:

```
>>> vars(e)
{'nombre': 'Cortana',
 'apellido': 'Microsoft',
 'edad': None,
 'sexo': None,
 'salario': 2000,
 'is_a_bot': True}
```

Answer (score 3):

Antes de nada, indicarte que, como *regla de estilo*, en python los nombres de las clases se ponen *capitalizados*: `Persona`, `Empleado`.

El funcionamiento de las herencias se basa en el mecanismo que tiene python para buscar atributos heradados entre las clases padres, relacionado con el denominado *Protocolo Descriptor*[^1](https://blog.ch3m4.org/2011/06/19/descriptores-parte-1/). Gracias a este mecanismo, funciona la *herencia múltiple*, las *metaclases*, las *propiedades* y las *clases abstractas*, por poner algunas características del lenguaje.

Entre poner:

```py
class Empleado(Persona):
    def __init__(self, nombre, apellido, edad, sexo, salario):
        super().__init__(nombre, apellido,edad, sexo)
```

y

```py
class Empleado(Persona):
    def __init__(self, nombre, apellido, edad, sexo, salario):
        Persona.__init__(self,nombre, apellido,edad, sexo)
```

diferen en quién se encarga de buscar el método `__init__` entre los *antecesores*. Con `Persona.__init__(self,...)` estás forzando a que la clase `Persona` use la instancia `self` y la inicialice. Con `super().__init__(...)` estás indicando a la instancia `self` que se inicialice como instancia de la clase superior (que no tiene porqué ser `Persona`, como luego veremos).

Para verlo mejor, vamos a añadir más clases, y dejaremos `Empleado` invocando directamente a `Persona`, sin `super()`:

```py
class Conductor(Persona):
    def __init__(self, ....):
        super().__init__(...)

class Viajante(Empleado, Conductor):
    def __init__(self, ....)
        super().__init__(...)
```

La primera observación es que en `Viajante` basta con una sola línea con `super()` para que funcione correctamente la inicialización de la instancia, tanto como `Empleado` como `Conductor`. ¿Cómo se consigue esto?

El truco se llama [**Algoritmo MRO**](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/). Sin entrar en detalles, este algoritmo aplica ciertos criterios por los que se ordenan, linealmente, toda la jerarquía de clases. En la práctica, convertimos una *jerarquía múltiple* en una *jeraquía simple*, siendo más fácil hacer búsquedas.

Veamos un ejemplo:

```py
pedro = Viajante(...)
```

El resultado del algoritmo MRO se almacena en el atributo de la clase `__mro__`. Si miramos en `Viajante.__mro__` vemos la tupla: `(Viajante, Empleado, Conductor, Persona, object)`. Éste será el orden de búsqueda que usará la instancia `pedro`, empezando por `Viajante` y acabando en `object`.

Usando `super()` estamos propagando la inicialización hacia arriba en la jerarquía de clases. `super()` obtiene el atributo `__mro__` del tipo de la instancia y lo coteja con la clase desde donde se invoca. De esta manera sabe cuál es la siguiente clase en la secuencia a donde pasar la llamada.

Así, el `super()` en `Viajante` ve que la siguiente clase en la cadena es `Empleado`. En `Empleado`, `super()` vería que la siguiente es `Conductor`, de ahí a `Persona`, y de ahí a `object`.

Pero en la clase `Empleado` habíamos dejado una llamada directa a `Persona.__init__`, sin usar `super()`, por lo que se saltaría la clase `Conductor` que era la correspondía por MRO.

Cuando programaste `Empleado` posiblemente funciona igual usando `super()` o haciendo la llamada directa. Pero si algún otro programador quisiera usar tu código, se podría encontrar con que no funciona la herancia múltiple como debería.

He intentado resumir bastante. No es necesario conocer el funcionamiento interno del algoritmo MRO para trabajar con la herencia múltiple. No obstante, puedes encontrarte con el error de que el algoritmo MRO no es capaz de serializar determinada jerarquía de clases. Lamentablemente, estos errores no son fáciles de resolver, ni aunque intentes comprender el algoritmo.

Comment: Lo lei pensando que era @Abulafia ...

Comment: La verdad es que confunde. Lo borraré en unos días.

Comment: @ChemaCortes no lo borres, lo entendi perfectamente ...